# Running maven command from Java using Runtime

Tags: java, maven, runtime

I am trying to run maven command from java main but it is not working for me as desired.

When i run the below code it runs the maven command on the same existing project in which this main class residing, but i want to run this maven command from this class to any another project folder.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

```
package com.codecoverage.runner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class MavenCoberturaRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

         Process p = null;

            try {
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/apache-maven-2.0.9/apache-maven-2.0.9/bin/mvn.bat clean cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.report.format=xml");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error on exec() method");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            copy(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
            p.waitFor();

        }

        static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
            while (true) {
                int c = in.read();
                if (c == -1)
                    break;
                out.write((char) c);
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use -f in command line

C:/apache-maven-2.0.9/apache-maven-2.0.9/bin/mvn.bat -f path/to/your/pom.xml clean cobertura:cobertura -Dcobertura.report.format=xml

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Runtime.exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)` method,
which executes the specified string command in a separate process with the specified environment and working directory.

What you want is to set working directory so it points to the place you need to run Maven at.